# Selenium Java Drag and drop

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, drag-and-drop, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to drag and drop using Selenium Java. It is clicking but not dropping it in the destination specified.

Code used for dragging and dropping:

```
WebElement drag= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/vr-modalbody/div/vr-form/div/vr-validation-group/vr-tabs/vr-tab[3]/vr-row/div/vr-columns/div/vr-validation-group/div/vr-directivewrapper/vr-rules-normalizenumbersettings/div/vr-row[1]/div/vr-columns/div/vr-toolbox/div/div[3]"));

//Drop    
        
WebElement Drop= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/vr-modalbody/div/vr-form/div/vr-validation-group/vr-tabs/vr-tab[3]/vr-row/div/vr-columns/div/vr-validation-group/div/vr-directivewrapper/vr-rules-normalizenumbersettings/div/vr-row[2]/div/vr-columns/div/div[2]/div/vr-validator/div/div[1]/vr-datagrid/vr-datagridrows/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]"));
    
Actions actions= new Actions(driver);
actions.clickAndHold(drag).build().perform();
actions.moveToElement(Drop).build().perform();
actions.release(Drop).build().perform();
```

Comment: On other note, try to avoid using absolute path for your elements. It will result in a fragile test case.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(drag));

    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.clickAndHold(drag).build().perform();
    actions.moveToElement(Drop).build().perform();
    actions.release(Drop).build().perform();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error occurred while dragging and dropping: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If this is not working, please share URL or page source code.

```
package selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class DragAndDropTest extends WebDriverSetup {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver(); // standard driver setup just wrapped
        driver.get("https://demoqa.com/droppable/");
        WebElement draggable = driver.findElement(By.id("draggable"));
        WebElement droppable = driver.findElement(By.id("droppable"));
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.dragAndDrop(draggable, droppable).build().perform();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        driver.quit();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to move to the element you want to drag. Besides, you can use chaining.

```
...(your codes are above)

actions.moveToElement(drag)
.clickAndHold()
.moveToElement(Drop)
.release(Drop).perform();
```